# Code for "Implicit Configurations" paper

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm trying to run this code in `ghci`:

http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/prepose/Prepose.hs

This is the code associated with the paper "Functional Pearl: Implicit Configurations"

http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/prepose/prepose.pdf

I'm sure I'm missing some `LANGUAGE` pragmas... I am getting the following error:

```
Prepose.hs:39:1: Parse error in pattern: normalize
```

Also, are there any hackage packages related to this paper?

Answer (score 4):

You can't apply a type signature to a function definition pattern.  This is the syntactically correct way to write it:

```
normalize :: (Modular s a, Integral a) => a -> M s a
normalize a = M (mod a (modulus (__ :: s))) :: M s a
```

However, that won't work.  What you really want is to refer to the type variable *s* in the function's type signature.  This can be done by using the ScopedTypeVariables extension, which requires explicit quantification:

```
normalize :: forall a s. (Modular s a, Integral a) => a -> M s a
normalize x = M (Mod x (modulus (__ :: s)))
```

As a suggestion to improve your code I recommend using the *tagged* library:

```
import Data.Proxy

modulus :: (Modular s a) => Proxy s -> a
```

That allows you to get along without ugly placeholder bottoms.  Another way to write it is:

```
modulus :: (Modular s a) => Tagged s a
```

This also gives you a nice conceptual benefit:  You now have two types, `Mod` for modular values and `Tagged` for their moduli.  You could define the type yourself, too, giving it a nicer name:

```
newtype Mod     s a = Mod     { residue :: a } 
newtype Modulus s a = Modulus { modulus :: a }
```

All this aside, if you want to make actual use of this, I recommend what ocharles said:  Use the [reflection](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) library.

Answer (score 3):

I can't help with the code problem, but Edward Kmett's [`reflection'](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) library is based on that paper.

Answer (score 2):

This completes the example from the paper using the `reflection` library. I'm basing this example off the [`Monoid`](https://github.com/ekmett/reflection/blob/master/examples/Monoid.hs) example in the library source.

```
data M a s = M a -- Note the phantom comes *after* the concrete

-- In `normalize` we're tying the knot to get the phantom types to align
-- note that reflect :: Reifies s a => forall proxy. proxy s -> a

normalize :: (Reifies s a, Integral a) => a -> M a s
normalize a = b where b = M (mod a (reflect b)) 

instance (Reifies s a, Integral a) => Num (M a s) where
  M a + M b = normalize (a + b)
  ...

withModulus :: Integral a => a -> (forall s. Reifies s a => M a s) -> a
withModulus m ma = reify m (runM . asProxyOf ma)
  where asProxyOf :: f s -> Proxy s -> f s
        asProxyOf a _ = a
```

Comment: Clever way to write it, although for clarity I prefer an explicit type signature.  I also recommend flipping the `Mod` type.

Comment: This is edwardk's method. I think to avoid `ScopedTypeVariables`.